# how to format inside JSON objects?

Tags: json, node.js, express

I have json object as follows:

```
var data = [{
    Id: '1285465',
    City: 'Singapore',
    Date: '2014-01-29 17:30:00.0'
    }, {
    Id: '1284429',
    City: 'Kuala Lumpur',
    Date: '2014-01-29 19:00:00.0'   
  }]
```

I have sent it to the view but before sending I want to change Date in the format 2014-01-29 only . How do I do it ?

```
data.forEach(function(item){
          moment(item.Date).format("YYYY-MM-DD"); //switched to moment

          });
```

I'm using express node.js

Comment: If the date is a string, you can simply iterate through all the objects in the array, and split by space to get the first part (the date). It is really simple. Give it a shot before just trying to get a solution from here.

Comment: tried it, but didnt work so i posted here.

 data.forEach(function(item){
          item.dateTime = format(item.dateTime);
          });

Comment: Describe "didnt work".

Comment: @jyoti you have not shown us the main part: The function to format the date,

Comment: it just seems to stop, right before iteration.It doesnt iterate and I dont know why

Comment: Can we see more of the code?

Comment: The code in the question does not assign the result of formatting the date to anything. So yeah, it will look like the loop is not executing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Moment.js` for that: http://momentjs.com/ (It could seems too much at first but this library can help you in many occasions)

In your example, to format your date into the right format, you can use:

```
  moment(item.Date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

And to install Moment.js just use: `npm install --save moment`

However, I think it might be a good practice to adapt your date to a display format at the last moment (Ohohoh). I mean, in your template.
What templating system did you choose?

Edit:

As for your iteration problem, the `forEach` method doesn't make any change to your object. You better have to use `map` and return the object modified with moment.

```
  if (trips) {

     trips = trips.map(function(item){
       item.dateTime = moment(item.dateTime).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
       return item;
     });

  }

  res.json(trips);
```

Comment: I'm using jade.

sorry guys, its not working. It seems to stop there.

Comment: I am joining Deestan on this, what are you calling "Not working"? We can help you.

Comment: still after mapping and returning it doesnt seem to solve the problem

could it be a problem because I have defined trips as var trips ?

Comment: Don't forget to affect the result to trips as well. Map is an immutable function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46340/discussion-between-aurelien-thieriot-and-jyoti)

Comment: ok the problem was because json was inside object

var data = ["test" :[{Id: '1285465',City: 'Singapore',Date: '2014-01-29 17:30:00.0'}, {Id: '1284429', City: 'Kuala Lumpur', Date: '2014-01-29 19:00:00.0' }]]

Comment: it is iterating now, but the problem is, it is not formatting the date. Says undefined

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved.

```
 data.map(function(item){
              item.Date = moment(item.Date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
              return date;

              });
```

This is the right way as already mentioned above. I had problems because i was referencing something else.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse JSON (you didn't show that code in your app), you can use `reviver` argument to turn strings to dates.